# Embed twitter timeline on website

Tags: html, twitter

I have seen a lot of questions and answers about embedding a single user's tweets on a webpage. But I cannot for the life of me find information on how to embed my actual timeline on a webpage. Like when I log in and see my timeline, I want to display that, not just my tweets. Like a 3rd party twitter app for a phone. I am working on a project and would have a user log into their twitter and it would display their feed on the site. Any tips on where to start?

Answer (score 1):

can you please review this following url,

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

Comment: I already did. That is not what I am looking for. That embeds a feed of tweets by one user. It's hard to explain the difference, but I need a user's actual timeline. Like a 3rd party twitter app that shows you your timeline and allows you to interact. Except I am not trying allow interactions, just show the user their timeline on the site.

Comment: I finally came across this. It seems to be what I am looking for. https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/userstreams